# How to change the background colour in Photos?

Tags: photos

In Photos, whenever I try to view a picture that is black in colour with a transparent background, such as many icons, the photo is not visible as the colour of the background is the same as the foreground. I want to change the background colour to white so that I 'm able to view such images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was filed as a bug in Photos in 2014, but it seems like it hasn't been fixed yet.

Consider raising attention to it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-photos/+bug/1394320